# MySQL: A better way to write this query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

We are using the following query in our system:

```
SELECT  f.type AS type, 
    COUNT(i.id) AS submissions,
    SUM((CASE (e.oiPost + e.oiPhone + e.oiEmail) 
            WHEN 0 THEN 0 
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 1
            WHEN 3 THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END))
FROM submission i
  LEFT JOIN fragment_live f ON f.ident = i.fragment_ident
  LEFT JOIN site s ON s.id = i.site_id
  LEFT JOIN entry e ON e.submission_id = i.id
WHERE i.submitted > '2012-04-01'
GROUP BY f.type;
```

I think for the purposes of this question, you probably won't need to know the full table structure.

However, what we're trying to do is get a total number of opt ins from the `entries` linked to the `submissions` we are already totalling. To qualify as an opt in, *either* `oiPost`, `oiPhone` or `oiEmail` needs to be 1. Not all submissions have a corresponding entry, however, so in those cases the join onto entry won't pull anything, and thus `oiPost`, `oiPhone` and `oiEmail` will be NULL.

The results of EXPLAIN are as follows:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                 | key                   | key_len | ref                      | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | ALL    | idx_submitted,idx_submitted_2 | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                     | 392795 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY               | 4       | gmg-api.i.Fragment_ident |      1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY               | 4       | gmg-api.i.Site_id        |      1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref    | UNIQ_2B219D70528302C6         | UNIQ_2B219D70528302C6 | 5       | gmg-api.i.id             |      1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

As it seems to be pertinent, here is the structure of the submission table:

```
CREATE TABLE `submission` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `forename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newsletter` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `additionalFields` longtext COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `submitted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Fragment_ident` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Territory_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` longtext,
  `postcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_DB055AF3A86F9784` (`Fragment_ident`),
  KEY `IDX_DB055AF36BC6912C` (`Territory_id`),
  KEY `IDX_DB055AF339002FDA` (`Site_id`),
  KEY `idx_submitted_ident` (`submitted`,`Fragment_ident`),
  KEY `idx_ident_submitted` (`Fragment_ident`,`submitted`),
  KEY `idx_submitted` (`submitted`),
  KEY `idx_sub_id_ident` (`submitted`,`id`,`Fragment_ident`),
  KEY `idx_sub_ident_id` (`submitted`,`Fragment_ident`,`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `submission_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Fragment_ident`) REFERENCES `fragment_live` (`ident`),
  CONSTRAINT `submission_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Territory_id`) REFERENCES `territory` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `submission_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Site_id`) REFERENCES `site` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=285274 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm just wondering if there is a better way we could write this query, or otherwise optimise it?

Comment: Do you have an index on `i.fragment_ident` ? If not add one and run again the explain. Your query should read a number of rows lower than 392795 for table `i` if it will use the new index

Comment: Just tried adding one, but it didn't change the number of rows. Nor does having one with both 'submitted' and 'fragment_ident'.

Comment: The thing that really stands out to me is the tablescan (`type` = `ALL` in the explain output) on `submission`. So either you don't have a suitable index for `submission.submitted`, or MySQL estimates that a large enough percentage of rows will pass through the filter that it's cheaper to just do a tablescan.

Comment: I've tried a few alternative options for indexes on the submission.submitted column. There is one ASC index, and one DESC index on there currently, but neither are used. Should I perhaps be looking into using an index length so that it only uses the Year and Month parts? Would that even work?

Comment: @Dan: There are no `DESC` indexes in MySQL. However you define them, all indexes are `ASC`.

Comment: I would try a compound index on `(fragment_ident, submitted)`

Comment: I've tried that, unfortunately. I've added the table structure to the original question to show you the indexes that are currently there.

Answer (score 1):

Note:  `1 + 1 + NULL = NULL`

For this reason I'd change one part...

```
SUM(CASE
      WHEN e.oiPost  = 1 THEN 1
      WHEN e.oiPhone = 1 THEN 1
      WHEN e.oiEmail = 1 THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
    END)                                  AS opt_ins
```

Why all the records in the submission table are being processed, I have no idea.  How many rows do you actually have that are `submitted > '2012-04-01'`?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM submission WHERE submitted > '2012-04-01'` results in 68,784 rows.

Comment: p.s. I made the change you suggested, thanks!